# pandoc incremental option on code block in html slideshow

Tags: html, markdown, slideshow, pandoc

I have a simple markdown slideshow I convert to html with pandoc

````
$ cat slides.md
% My lovely presentation

# My lovely first slide
- first bullet
- second bullet
- third bullet
```c
for (int i=0;i<10;i++) { ... }
``
$ pandoc -i -t slidy -s slides.md -o slides.html
````

I want the code block to appear *after* the third bullet, but it's there from the start. Is it doable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add it as part of a fourth bullet point:

````
% My lovely presentation

# My lovely first slide

- first bullet
- second bullet
- third bullet
- ```c
  for (int i=0;i<10;i++) { ... }
  ```
````

see https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#incremental-lists